# Pandas - How to extract values from a large DF without any 'keys' using another DF's values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got one large matrix as a pandas DF w/o any 'keys' but plain numbers on top. A smaller version of that just to demonstrate the problem in here would be like this input:

```
M=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,5))
```

What I want to accomplish is using another given DF as reference that has a structure like this

```
N=pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,2,2],'B':[2,3,4]})
```

...to extract the values from the large DF whereas the values of 'A' correspond to the **ROW** number  and 'B' values to the **COLUMN** number of the **large DF** so that the expected output would look like this:

```
Large DF
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.766275  0.910825  0.378541  0.775416  0.639854
1  0.505877  0.992284  0.720390  0.181921  0.501062
2  0.439243  0.416820  0.285719  0.100537  0.429576
3  0.243298  0.560427  0.162422  0.631224  0.033927

Small DF
   A  B
0  2  2
1  2  3
2  2  4

Expected Output:
   A  B extracted values 
0  2  2 0.285719
1  2  3 0.100537
2  2  4 0.429576
```

So far I've tried different version of something like this

```
N['extracted'] = M.iloc[N['A'].astype(int):,N['B'].astype(int)]
```

..but it keeps failing with an error saying

```
TypeError: cannot do positional indexing on RangeIndex with these indexers
[0    2
 1    2
 2    2
```

Which approach would be the best ?
Is this job better to accomplish by converting the DF's into a numpy arrays ?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use the apply function. This goes row by row through your data set.

```
N['extracted'] = N.apply(lambda row: M.iloc[row['A'], row['B']], axis=1)
```

Comment: Great help thanks. Just wondering, how would it be in case of column by column e.g go to column "2" and apply 'B' row by row. Simply "axis=0" would fail, won't it ?

Comment: Yes, correct. Keep in mind that you change both the direction of the apply function where you set the value. with df['col_name'] you set a column. With .loc[row, col] you can set either. This function adds the first and second values up: N.loc['sum_one_and_two'] = N.apply(lambda column: column[0] + column[1], axis=0)